# How to model a dataset given by a simulation software to an equation

Tags: polynomials, regression

I have a dataset which is produced using a software. I will attach the dataset to this post via [a dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xqlu4jakze3y7tu/dataset?dl=1) as it is too long to attach to this post. My intention is to come up with a equation that will draw a line which will go through most points of this dataset for x values presented on the left column. The accuracy of the line is of very high interest to me. I have been using a regression based tool so far for my work. it is linked below.

http://arachnoid.com/polysolve/

However for this dataset, that tool is performing very poorly. Because of this problem, the model which produces other results is not producing accurate results. I am using MATLAB simulink to input this dataset. Basically, I fidn the equation from the above website and paste it to a MATLAB simulink function box. Therefore, for a given x input, the box outputs the proper y value.

I would highly appreciate a better, more accurate solution for my problem if it is possible.

Comment: I shall try to give you an almost exact answer tomorrow morning.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: You are very welcome. What I plan to do, if feasible, is to give the exact numbers corresponding to your input file. I hope it will work but it requires some work and I have to go now. I shall work on that tomorrow morning (it is almost 1:00pm here). Cheers.

Comment: I completely understand. Please do take your time. Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of data you sent me contains a lot of noise; this is obvious just making a scatter plot of them and I do not think that there is any way to do a good job with them using polynomial regression.

I reproduce below the sum of squares as a function of the degree of the polynomial as well as the corresponding adjusted $R^2$.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\text{degree} & \text{SSQ} & \text{adj. R}^2\\
 1 & 109.1 &0.494292\\
 2 & 44.4392& 0.793105\\
 3 & 25.4521 &0.880979\\
 4 & 12.554 &0.941033\\
 5 & 10.471 &0.950597\\
 6 & 10.0505 &0.952369\\
 7 & 9.9772 &0.952503\\
 8 & 9.54288&0.954365
\end{array}
\right)$$

Visually, it seems that degree $6$ would not bee "too" bad (but, for most parameters, the coefficients are not significant from a statistical point of view). It write $$y=6.16364\times 10^7 x^6-165894. x^5-99058.5 x^4+1975.35 x^3+149.302 x^2-9.00162
   x+0.0553619$$

Let us see what you can do with that.

Comment: truly appreciate your time.